# What's the fastest way to clear the screen in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to PyGame and I'm working on creating a simple 2D solar system simulation with minimal graphics. It involves drawing text and circles to the screen, then moving them and redrawing them. Up until now I've made a function for each object in the simulation which redraws over it's previous position in black (as the background is black) as a way of clearing the old frame before it redraws itself.

However I've been wondering if this is the fastest way to do it? Its quite tedious to implement for every object and if I wanted to have a background image it wouldn't work. I've sort of shied away from doing `screen.fill((0,0,0))` every frame as it seems like a lot of it is unnecessary (as I only have a small portion of the screen covered by circles / text at once.).

Is there an faster way of doing this that I'm missing, or is `screen.fill((0,0,0))` the best option? I'm trying to maximize performance / frame-rate, and I've done framerate tests on both methods and neither method seems better than the other.

Comment: You have the choice: Either low effort, high waste (`screen.fill`) or high effort, low waste. But keep in mind that `screen.fill` will probably still be faster since it happens outside of python and everything outside of python is faster. (And yes, this question does not belong onto SO, therefor this is not an answer)

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to SO so can I get clarification on why it doesn't belong here?

Comment: This falls into the category of opinion-based questions: You are asking for the best way to do something, but there is not definite best way: Do you want best performance? Do you want clean code? What would clean code mean? (If you had said what is the fastest way of doing something it would have been OK)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I'll edit my question

Comment: This question is not an opinion, that's YOUR opinion, @megalng, and it's incorrect. A valid question is whether screen.fill is efficient. Your response clutters SO. If screen.fill is efficient because it happens at a level below Python, then that is the answer to this query. (don't worry about screen.fill being wasteful---it's not).